# remove rows with today's date pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a df with several columns, and I want to remove rows that have today's date time.

```
     col1               col2                  col3                col4
     ABC       2022-08-12 00:03:29.872         123                A1B2
     BCD       2022-08-12 00:02:08.067         234                B1C2
     CDE       2022-08-11 23:57:24.208         345                C1D2   
     DEF       2022-08-11 23:56:55.257         456                D1E2
```

expected result (assuming today's date is 12th august 2022):

```
     col1               col2                  col3                col4
     CDE       2022-08-11 23:57:24.208         345                C1D2   
     DEF       2022-08-11 23:56:55.257         456                D1E2
```

I tried doing below

```
    df[pd.to_datetime(df.col2, errors='coerce') < pd.to_datetime('today')]
```

but it is not working, I still get rows from today. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with `!=` [`Timestamp.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.date.html):

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df.col2, errors='coerce').dt.date != pd.to_datetime('today').date()]
print (df)
  col1                    col2  col3  col4
2  CDE 2022-08-11 23:57:24.208   345  C1D2
3  DEF 2022-08-11 23:56:55.257   456  D1E2
```